# Why the APK file created by Android Studio is different from APK created by Eclipse?

Tags: android, android-studio, eclipse-adt

I have developed an Android application in Eclipse and used the `APK` generated by Eclipse, now I have moved to Android Studio as it is Official IDE for Android development. I have imported the project in Android Studio and got the `APK` file.

The problem is if I install the new `APK` (Generated by Android Studio) in my device that has the old `APK`(Generated by Eclipse) installed on it, then device is showing a message **"An existing package by same name with a conflicting signature is already installed"**.

My Question is why both `APK` files are different if both is developed and generated from same PC?

Comment: why are people downvoting.. I think this question deserve answer.

Comment: Your Eclipse/ADT signing configuration is different from your Android Gradle plugin signing configuration. They can be configured to use the same key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android studio is having gradle feature  which builds apk a way different than the eclipse thats why different signature .

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have two Android SDKs on your PC which means you may have two different default keystore on your PC (Or maybe you reinstalled your SDK so the default keystore is changed).

You can find your keystore at here:

```
OS X and Linux: ~/.android/

Windows Vista and Windows 7: C:\Users\your_user_name\.android\
```

This problem won't happen if you generate a specific keystore for your application. Later no matter which PC you use, the generated APK can always overwrite the previous version (means previous version are signed by the same keystore, and the version code is smaller).

Comment: Can we use the keystore file (created by Eclipse) to sign the APK in Android Studio?

Comment: Short answer is yes, you can. But do you still have the old keystore?

Comment: Ok. No, for this application I don't have keystore, but I have keystore of some other apps and when I will make changes in the these app then I will have to use the keysores of those application.